# Is there a way to add .trim() on the back of a jquery selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For a project in my JavaScript class we're required to fetch a json object from flickr using their API defined by a set of tags the user enters; I've successfully done that, however I'd like to cover up a few cracks I've made while writing the algorithm.

For my search bar I'm checking:

```
($('#search').val().length == 0)
```

In order to make sure they have at least entered something. The problem I'm facing however is that if one is to type in spaces the spaces are still counted as characters.

My question is, is if I can do something like the following:

```
($('#search').trim().val().length == 0)
```

It seems, that this by itself doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `$('#search').val().trim().length == 0` - first find the value and then trim the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) works on strings and removes leading and trailing spaces.

```
$('#search').trim().val().length
```

will try to execute `trim()` on object and thus will throw an error.

You first have to get the value(string) of the element and then trim it.

```
$('#search') // Select the element
    .val()   // Get it's value
    .trim()  // trim leading & trailing spaces
    .length  // Then get the length
```

or using jQuery [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
$.trim($('#search').val()).length
```

Comment: Ah! This was what was confusing me. I had thought .trim and $.trim were the same thing. Thank you for the insight; I won't be making this mistake  again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would want to run `trim` on the string not the DOM input so simply reverse it to:

`($('#search').val().trim().length == 0)`